# Trying to read csv data and compare to web table in java

Tags: java, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver, csvreader

I'm trying to compare the data on my csv file to web table.
`

```
WebElement mytable1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dStocks1"));
        // To locate rows of table.
        List<WebElement> rows_table1 = mytable1.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        // To calculate no of rows In table.
        int rows_count1 = rows_table1.size();
String path = (filePath);

            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line;
            String splitBy = ",(?=([^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)";
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            System.out.println("\n CSV data: ");
            br.readLine();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int col = 1; col < line.length();) {
                    for (int row = 1; row < rows_count1;) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        String[] cells = line.split(splitBy);
                        List<WebElement> rows_table2 = mytable1.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
                        List<WebElement> Columns_row = rows_table2.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
                        int columns_count = Columns_row.size();
                        System.out.println("Number of cells In Row " + row + " are " + columns_count);
                        for (int column = 1; column < columns_count; column++) {

                            String celtext = Columns_row.get(column).getText();
                            String col1 = cells[col].substring(1, cells[col].length() - 1);
                            assertEquals(celtext, col1);

                            System.out.print(" CELL: " + column + " " + col1 +"\n");
                            br.readLine();
                            col++;

                        }
                        
                        row++;
                        System.out.println("  ");

                    }

                }
            }
```

`

This is the result
`

```
Number of cells In Row 1 are 9
 CELL: 1 Requested
 CELL: 2 PO0815454781
 CELL: 3 Main Office Stockroom
 CELL: 4 09/13/2022
 CELL: 5 DR1212475112
 CELL: 6 09/20/2022
 CELL: 7 TGP
 CELL: 8 3,000,000.00
  
 
Number of cells In Row 2 are 9
PASSED: export
FAILED: exportRequested
Index 9 out of bounds for length 9
```

`

The last index of my csv file is '8' but after printing the `line.length` it display '115' and that is the problem. My index is out of bounds. Can someone help me with this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the csv reading part first. You can use something like this:

```
public class CSVReader {
    private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";


    private static List<String> getRecordFromLine(String line) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner rowScanner = new Scanner(line)) {
            rowScanner.useDelimiter(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            while (rowScanner.hasNext()) {
                values.add(rowScanner.next());
            }
        }
        return values;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("src/test/resources/test.csv"));) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                records.add(getRecordFromLine(scanner.nextLine()));
            }
        }
        records.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

CSV content:

```
data1
data4
data7
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it with `FileReader` and `CsvReader`. You can try something like this:

```
 public String readCsv(String path) {

    try {

        FileReader filereader = new FileReader(path);

        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(filereader);
        String[] nextRecord;

        while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            for (String cell : nextRecord) {
                return cell;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Something went wrong. Path to file is wrong or cell not found.");
}
```